# How do we find the Q-factor of a fourth order active-RC filter?

Tags: filter

How do we find the Q-factor of a fourth order active-RC filter? The filter in question is not developed by cascading lower order filters.

Answer (score 1):

> The filter in question is not developed by cascading lower order
>   filters.

It may not be physically constructed by cascading 2 filters but it can be analysed as if it were and, it will yield two Q factors; one for each 2nd order stage.

In the bigger picture, Q factor is a 2nd order filter phenomenon.

Answer (score 1):

A fourth-order lowpass has **two pairs of complex poles**. Each pole pair has a characteristic q-factor Qp which is called "pole-Q". This quantity Qp can be found by using the following definition:

**Qp=wp/2*Re(wp)**

with

- wp: pole frequency (magnitude of the vector between the origin and the pole) and
- Re(wp): Real part of the pole (sigma).

Comment: Because the pole location is NOT dependent on the chosen filter topology, the same applies to the corresponding  quality factors: The Qp values do not depend on the filter structure.